# Change VS Ui when switching from code to designer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to make Visual Studio (2010) alter its layout (switch prespective) depending the type of entity you are editing?

My problem is that I do not want to see `toolbox` and `properties` windows when writing code, while showing `Visual Assist's` windows (plugin).

What I know is that visual studio supports this in Coding/Debug mode where you can arrange windows as you like and have it applied when running a project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139710/hide-properties-toolbox-pane-when-not-in-resource-view